Help needed with an integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x) \ln(1+x) }{1+x^2} dx$.
I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x) \ln(1+x) }{1+x^2} dx $$
Integration by parts gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x) \tan^{-1}(x) }{1+x} dx  + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x) \ln(1+x) }{1+x^2} dx 
+ \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x) \ln(1+x) }{x} dx =0.
\end{eqnarray*}
The first integral has been done here  Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x \log x}{1+x}dx$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x) \tan^{-1}(x) }{1+x} dx  = -\frac{ \pi^3}{64} + \frac{1}{2} K \ln(2).
\end{eqnarray*}
Any hints or solutions on how to approach the other integrals will be gratefully recieved.

See this answer as well as the parent post

Denote $I= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx $ and $J=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx
\overset{x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}}= J
-2 I-2G\ln2+\frac{\pi^3}{16}\\
&\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx
= J+ \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}\overset{x\to \frac1x}{dx}
= 2J-2I+\frac{\pi^3}{16}
\end{align}
Eliminate $J$
\begin{align}
I=&\ \frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2} \overset{t=1+x}{dx}-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}\overset{t=1-x}{dx}-2G\ln2+\frac{\pi^3}{32}\\
=& \ \frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2t}{1+(t-1)^2}dt
-\frac32\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}{dx}-2G\ln2+\frac{\pi^3}{32}\tag1
\end{align}
where $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx =2\Im\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)
$
\begin{align}
 &\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2t}{1+(t-1)^2}dt
=\int_0^\infty \frac{(t^2+2t+2)\ln^2t}{t^4+4}dt
=\frac{7\pi^3}{64}+\frac{3\pi}{16}\ln^22\\
\end{align}
Plug into (1) to obtain
$$
I=-3\Im\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right) -2G\ln2
+\frac{3\pi}{32}\ln^22+\frac{11\pi^3}{128}$$

Using Feynman's trick.
$$I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x) \log(1+ax) }{1+x^2}\, dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^1\frac{x \log (x)}{\left(x^2+1\right) (a x+1)}\,dx$$
$$I'(a)= \frac 1 {a^2+1} \int_0^1\Bigg(\frac{x \log (x)}{ x^2+1}+\frac{a
   \log (x)}{x^2+1}-\frac{a \log (x)}{a x+1}\Bigg) \,dx$$
$$J_1=\int_0^1 \frac{x \log (x)}{ x^2+1} \,dx=-\frac{\pi ^2}{48}$$
$$J_2=a\int_0^1 \frac{ \log (x)}{ x^2+1} \,dx=-a C$$
$$J_3=-a\int_0^1 \frac{ \log (x)}{ ax+1} \,dx=-a \text{Li}_2(-a)$$
Simplify and recombine
$$I'(a)=\frac{J_1+J_2+J_3}{1+a^2}=-\frac{a C}{a^2+1}-\frac{\pi ^2}{48\left(a^2+1\right)}-\frac{\text{Li}_2(-a)}{a^2+1}$$
$$I(a)=\int_0^1 I'(a)\, da=-\frac{1}{2} C \log (2)-\frac{\pi ^3}{192}+\int_0^1 \frac {J_3}{1+a^2} \,da$$
The last integral is not the most pleasant (but Wolfram Alpha gives the antiderivative- see here)
$$\int_0^1 \frac {J_3}{1+a^2} \,da=\frac{35 \pi ^3}{384}-\frac{3}{2} C \log (2)+$$
$$\frac i{64}\left(192 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)-105
   \zeta (3)-4 \log ^3(2)-6 i \pi  \log ^2(2)+5 \pi ^2 \log
   (2)\right)$$
So, as a total
$$K=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x) \log(1+ax) }{1+x^2}\, dx=\frac{11 \pi ^3}{128}-2 C \log (2)+\frac{3}{32} \pi  \log ^2(2)+$$
$$\frac i{64} \left(192 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)-105
   \zeta (3)-4 \log ^3(2)+5 \pi ^2 \log (2)\right)$$
